# Autolayout (with Masonry) with corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I would like to layout a circular UIImageView with Masonry. So I have created the UIImageView like this:

```
[self.imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.mas_centerX);
    make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top).with.offset([[UIView ub_padding] floatValue]);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.descriptionLabel.mas_top).with.offset(-[[UIView ub_padding] floatValue]);
    make.height.equalTo(self.descriptionLabel.mas_height).priorityHigh();
    make.width.equalTo(self.imageView.mas_height);
}];
```

I then created the constraints for the ImageView

```
[self.imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.mas_centerX);
    make.top.equalTo(self.mas_top).with.offset([[UIView ub_padding] floatValue]);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.descriptionLabel.mas_top).with.offset(-[[UIView ub_padding] floatValue]);
    make.height.equalTo(self.descriptionLabel.mas_height).priorityHigh();
    make.width.equalTo(self.imageView.mas_height);
}];
```

I then tried to have these constraints applied and then set the corner radius.

```
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width/2;
```

But the frame of `self.imageView` is still unset (but it does get layed out later when I view it on the simulator). What method is called when the layout is done?

Comment: Are you looking for the `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method? It's called every time a view controller does layout.

Comment: I don't know Masonry. That is why I don't write this as an answer. Apparently you have access to the UIImageView object and its layer. Dis you set `self.imageView.layer.maskksToBounds=YES;` ?

Comment: I noticed that, but I was hoping that the UIView itself would have a method like that...

Answer (score 1):

Setup your corner radius after calling `super...` in your view's `layoutSubviews` method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self applyCornerRadii];
}
```

This ensures layout has occurred before attempting to apply corner radii (which in my case is 50% of the height/width to create a circle), and it is calculated correctly.